Questions on the compactness of $L_1([0,1]^2)$'s unit sphere
Let $U$ denote the set of functions $f\in L_1([0,1]^2)$ such that $\int f=1$ and $f(x,y)\geq 0: a.e. (x,y)\in [0,1]^2$.  Recently in my study I need to study the compactness of $U$. By Riesz's theorem we know $U$ isn't compact under the $L_1$-norm. So I need to study its compactness under weaker topology version. Let $C([0,1]^2)$ denote the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]^2$.
Question 1  Is the following true: Let $\{f_i\}$ be a sequence in $U$ such that for every $h \in C([0,1]^2)$ and for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N > 0$ such that for every $i, j > N$ we have $\int (f_i - f_j) h < \varepsilon$. Then there exists $f_0 \in U$ such that for every $h \in C([0,1]^2)$, $ \lim_{i \to \infty} \int (f_i - f_0) h \to 0.$
If Question 1 is right, does change $C$ by $L_1$ or $L_{\infty}$ also right?(someone tells me Prokhorov's theorem maybe helpful but I'm not sure whether it is correct :( )
Question 2 Let $V$ denote the set of functions $f\in C([0,1]^2)$ such that $\int f=1$ and $f(x,y)>0: a.e. (x,y)\in [0,1]^2$. Does the closure of $V$ equal to $U$ under $L_1$-norm? (or some other norm)
Thank you very much for reading my question! :)

This is a cross-post of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4985876/questions-on-the-compactness-of-l-10-12s-unit-sphere. Please don't cross-post to multiple sites at short intervals (e.g., wait a week on the first site), and in case you do cross-post, please state it explicitly in the question. Thanks.

Does "contions" mean "continuous" ?

@DanielAsimov yes sorry for mistake, I edit it

@JeanAbouSamra well sorry I ask it in two webset because I'm not sure whether it is research-level question or not(if this question is proper to ask in MO, I'd like to keep my question on this webset)....I'm not majored in analysis but my research really need this

Question 1 sounds a bit unclear. Would you state the hypotheses using quantifiers (assume $\forall\dots\exists$, in proper order) instead of the ambiguous any?

@PietroMajer ok,I edit now

sorry but as it is written,  you are assuming there is  $N$ such that  the inequality holds for every $h$, which is only true if the sequence is eventually constant , $\forall  j>N, f_j=f$  (so the answer is trivially yes)

Maybe you mean:
$$$$
Question 1 Is the following true: Let ${f_i}$ be a sequence in $U$ such that  for every $h\in C([0,1]^2)$ and for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that for every $i,j>N$ we have $\int(f_i-f_j)h< \varepsilon$. Then there exists $f_0\in U$ such that for every $h\in C([0,1]^2)$  $\lim_{i\to\infty}\int(f_i-f_0)h\to 0.$
$$$$
Then the assumption on ${f_i}\subset U$ can be stated equivalently: $$$$
For all $h\in C([0,1]^2)$ the sequence $\int f_ih $ converges in $\mathbb R$.$$$$
(and the answer would be no)

@PietroMajer yes, this is what I mean! I edit the question now. And could the answer be yes by strengthen its some statement? thank you very much!

The assumption on $(f_i)_i\subset U$ can be stated equivalently: For all $h\in C([0,1]^2)$, the sequence $\int f_ih $ is Cauchy on $\mathbb R$, or also, equivalently:
For all $h\in C([0,1]^2)$ it is convergent in $\mathbb R.$ (Or also: $(f_i)_i$ is a $w^*$ Cauchy sequence in $C([0,1]^2)^*$).
Then the answer is no:
Consider e.g. the sequence $$f_j(x,y):=\frac{4^j\pi}{{2j\choose j}}\sin^{2j}(x-y).$$ Then $f_j\ge0$, $\int_0^1f_j(x,y)dx= \int_0^1f_j(x,y)dy=1$ for all $x,y$; for all $h\in C([0,1]^2)$ one has $\int_0^1\int_0^1f_j(x,y)h(x,y)dxdy\to \int_0^1h(t,t)dt$; however for no $f\in L_1([0,1]\times[0,1])$ one has$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)h(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^1h(t,t)dt$$ for all  $h\in C([0,1]^2)$.
(In other words, $f_j$ converges $w^*$ to the uniform normalised $1$-dimensional measure on the diagonal, which is not absolutely continuous w.r.to the $2$ dimensional Lebesgue measure).
If however the assumption of $(f_j)$ is strengthen asking: For all $h\in L^\infty([0,1]^2)$ the sequence $\int f_jh$ converges, that is,  $(f_j)$ is a weak Cauchy sequence, then it is true, because the weak topology $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$ is complete and $U$ is weakly closed. (But also note that, since $L^\infty$ is not separable, in general you are not able to extract a weak Cauchy subsequence from an arbitrary sequence in $U$).
